# Webscraping in Python: strange order and scraping problem

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I'm doing some webscraping and something very strange is happening and I cannot come up with what is causing the problem neither the solution...

I'm using this for that goes through a list of links, opens them and saves in 3 lists all the values contained in the class tags I ask for, here is the code:

```
for link in list_links:
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(link).content, "html.parser")
for title in soup.find_all(class_="im-features__title"):
    info_annunci_title.append(title.get_text(strip=True))

for value in soup.find_all(class_="im-features__value"):
    info_annunci_value.append(value.get_text(strip=True))

for altro in soup.find_all(class_="im-features__tag"):
    info_annunci_altro.append(altro.get_text(strip=True))
```

After this I'm using a nested for that goes through 3 zipped lists in parallel to search inside the 3 previous lists for all the values I actually need to save.

Code:

```
    for t, v, a in zip(info_annunci_title, info_annunci_value, info_annunci_altro):
    # Crea oggetti JSON per ogni annuncio salvato
    if "tipologia" in t:
        list_annunci.append(v)

    if "superficie" in t:
        list_annunci.append(v)

    if "piano" in t:
        list_annunci.append(v)

    if "piani edificio" in t:
        list_annunci.append(v)

    if "prezzo" in t:
        list_annunci.append(v)

    if "Auto" in t:
        list_annunci.append(v)

    if "Balcone" in a:
        list_annunci.append(a)

    if "Cantina" in a:
        list_annunci.append(a)

    if "Terrazza" in a:
        list_annunci.append(a)
```

At this point here comes the strange problem... I get good results for nearly all of the ads I'm looking into, apart from the first and a few of the last ones, here is the output:

**id: 0
Appartamento
Balcone
95 m² | commerciale 100 m²                 -Vedi dettaglio
id: 1
Appartamento
110 m² | commerciale 142 m²                 -Vedi dettaglio
Piano terra, con accesso disabili
2 piani
1 in garage/box
Terrazza
Cantina
€ 339.000
id: 2
Balcone
Appartamento
170 m² | commerciale 174 m²                 -Vedi dettaglio
Cantina
Piano terra, con ascensore**

The format may be difficult to read, sorry, be aware that an ad starts with "id: num" and should end with a price in €...

As you can see the first add is completely missing apart from 1 data.

At the end it even goes crazier like this:

**id: 109
Balcone
id: 110
id: 111
id: 112
id: 113
id: 114
id: 115
Balcone
id: 116
Balcone**

P.S: I noticed that the order of the info is wrong for some reason. It should always find **appartamento** (apartment) as the first element, but for some reason it gets the wrong info, like **balcone** or **terrazza**.

What is creating this strange error and how can I solve it/where did I go wrong?

Usefult links:

[Link to page with all ad links](https://www.immobiliare.it/vendita-case/ancona/borgo-rodi/?criterio=rilevanza)

[Page in screenshot](https://www.immobiliare.it/annunci/87953208/)

Image of the website and how the actual order should be, instead it gets things before than the real first items...

[image: Image of the part of ad I'm scraping]

Comment: Can you share the link to the website?

Comment: @PraysonW.Daniel yeah sure, sorry I forgot! This is the ad page I'm using right now! https://www.immobiliare.it/vendita-case/ancona/borgo-rodi/?criterio=rilevanza ---- If you click on this ad: https://www.immobiliare.it/annunci/87953208/ you will se the page I used for the screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

To get all information from the ads, you ca use next example:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def get_info(ad_url):
    out = {}
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(ad_url).content, "html.parser")
    for t, v in zip(
        soup.select(".im-features__title"), soup.select(".im-features__value")
    ):
        tags = v.select(".im-features__tag")
        if tags:
            for tag in tags:
                out[tag.get_text(strip=True)] = "X"
        else:
            out[t.get_text(strip=True, separator=" ")] = v.get_text(strip=True)
    return out


url = "https://www.immobiliare.it/vendita-case/ancona/borgo-rodi/?criterio=rilevanza"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "lxml")

out = []
for li in soup.select('li[id^="link_ad_"]'):
    link = li.a
    print(link["href"])
    out.append({"Name": link.get_text(strip=True), "URL": link["href"]})
    out[-1].update(get_info(link["href"]))

df = pd.DataFrame(out)
print(df)
df.to_csv("data.csv", index=None)
```

Creates `data.csv` (screenshot from LibreOffice):

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, but I'm trying to understand what I did wrong in my code. Anywho your answer is really useful for another way of working on this. Do you know what is causing such a problem in my code?

Answer (score 0):

I actually found the solution on my own trying different setting, a problem still occurs so I will add it to this answer and won't flag it as final answer...

It was very stupid and easy, I just had to control the inserting order as the title could be more than the values or viceversa. This nested for's did the job.

Still a problem persists, duplicating data such as in the second image I'll insert.

[image: Solution]

Duplicating results:

[image: Bugs]